# how to get a rounded down difference of two dates SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a int that represent the difference *rounded down* of a date (eCreationTime) and today (now).

I've tried with this code but you can notice that the col datediff doesn't show me 4 but 5

[image]

```
SELECT h.efolderid, eCreationTime,GETDATE() as now, datediff(year,eCreationTime,GETDATE()) as datediff FROM tableOne h inner join tableTwo on h.eFolderID =e.eFolderID
```

Comment: What do you mean by "rounded down"?  What units?

Comment: What do you mean the "rounded down" value of a date? Dates aren't numbers, you don't round them.

Comment: the difference of the col "ecreationtime" and the col "now" give me 5 but you can see that the month in ecreationtime is in december (12) and now we are in october (10), so the result that I want in the column datediff is 4! :D

Comment: Start by reading the documentation. Datediff does not do what you think it does. It counts boundaries crossed. Datediff (year, '20191231', '20200101') returns 1 because 1 year boundary was crossed despite the fact that there is only 1 day difference between them.

Comment: @SMor so what should I use? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A more accurate solution is :

```
SELECT h.efolderid, eCreationTime, GETDATE() as now,
       FLOOR(datediff(day,eCreationTime,GETDATE()) / 365.2425) as datediff 
FROM   tableOne h 
       inner join tableTwo 
          on h.eFolderID =e.eFolderID
```

But with leap years the solution wont'be true for some specific dates arround the 29 of february...

Comment: nice, even if this is not really accurate

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You can use `case` logic:

```
select (year(getdate()) - year(e.CreationTime) -
        (case when month(getdate()) < month(e.CreationTime)  then 1
              when month(getdate()) = month(e.CreationTime) and
                   day(getdate()) < day(e.CreationTime) then 1
              else 0
         end)
       ) as diff
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=18a1c8d3bc59b69ab681391a20bba236) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: that gives me 5 too :(

Comment: @FedericoPapetti . . . Right idea.  Wrong logic.  I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Find the different in month and than divide by 12

```
; with tbl as
(
    select  eCreationTime = convert(datetime, '2015-12-03 11:25:35.393'),
            [now]         = convert(datetime, '2020-10-07 12:20:14.427')
)
select  eCreationTime, [now],
        [datediff] = datediff(month, eCreationTime, [now]) / 12
from    tbl
```